# pkcs11-tool: why do I need to specify a module to load?

Tags: pkcs#11

When I run pkcs11-tool I always need to specify a module:

```
pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so -L
```

What is this module for and how pkcs11-tool use it? Which are the other possible modules I can use? What is the difference between them?

I tried to use another one ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so"), but I always get an empty slot, so I suppose there is a difference in the purpose of the modules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modules are used as middleware to the actual device like smart cards, USB tokens and hardware security modules (HSMs) or even software emulations for PKCS#11.

You can think of it as a hardware driver mapping PKCS#11 to the concrete device, with some modules offering vendor-specific algorithms, login mechanisms etc.

Some known modules are listed here:
http://wiki.ncryptoki.com/Known-PKCS-11-modules.ashx

Using OpenSC, you already have support for a lot of different devices:

https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Supported-hardware-(smart-cards-and-USB-tokens)

So given you stick to those devices listed there and don't use any special function not supported by OpenSC, you should use OpenSC.